# The distance between two points needs to be measured

Tags: probability

The distance between two points needs to be measured, in meters. The true distance between the points is 10 meters, but due to measurement error we can’t measure the distance exactly. Instead, we will observe a value of 10 + ε, where the error ε is distributed N (0, 0.04). Find the probability that the observed distance is within 0.4 meters of the true distance (10 meters). Give both an exact answer in terms of Φ and an approximate numerical answer.

- I got the mean = 0, Standard deviation = 0.2, and the probability $P(-0.4 < ε < 0.4)$

$P(\frac{-0.4 - μ}{σ}<\frac{ ε- μ}{σ}<\frac{0.4 - μ}{σ})$ = $P(\frac{-0.4 - 0}{0.2}<\frac{ ε- 0}{0.2}<\frac{0.4 - 0}{0.2})$ = $Φ(2) - Φ(-2)$ but I am not sure of the numeric answer approximation because I am having trouble calculating it using a calculator.

- However, I am not sure if my word thus far is correct. It seems a little off I just don't know where. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else checks this question, the calculations above are correct. It can be further reduced as:

$$\Phi(2)-\Phi(-2)=\Phi(2)-(1-\Phi(2))=\Phi(2)-1+\Phi(2)=2\Phi(2)-1$$